# dnsmasq fails a few seconds, then get back to normal (debian)

Tags: debian-squeeze, dnsmasq

I am running a box with `debian 6.0.8`, and `DNSMasq 2.55` (from Debian repository).

I use it to resolve some local hostnames, and it mostly works fine. but some times, it will fail to answer requests for a few seconds, and then gets back to normal again.

I am just wondering what could cause these "gaps"?

I have not seen anything wrong in syslog or anything.

Comment: This might restart of the service on your box for some maintenace work (logrotate f.e.)

check if it is happening every day on the same time (cronjob) or in a similiar timeframe

Comment: I do not see any cronjobs that fits. it happens relatively often it seems.. but only for a few seconds at the time.